# Find string section that contains another String, with possible intervening words

Tags: java, text-search

For the last project of the semester, the goal is to run searches of a particular phrase on a lyric String inside an Song object, then rank the results based on the length of the substring match.  The lyrics were read from a file and match the line breaks in that file.

For example, searching for "She loves you" would return these in the sample matches:

The Beatles: "... **She loves you**, yeah, yeah, yeah ..."  Rank= 13 characters
Bonnie Raitt: "... **She** just **loves you** ..." Rank= 18 characters
Elvis Presley: "... You're asking if **she loves** me\r\nWell, **you** don't know..." Rank= 23 characters

As you can see from the last example, matches can span multiple lines.

I have all the songs in a `TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Song>>`, so I get all the songs that match the first word in the query.  The difficulty I'm having is searching the String for matches, since a regex won't work in this situation.

When the Song object is constructed, I dumped the lyrics into a Set to run searches for a single word, and to do that I used `String.split("[^a-zA-Z}")` to separate out the individual words and weed out the punctuation marks.  So I want to run my search on that array.  The process I'm using goes like:

```
break up the query into a String array
  for each Song in the set
    if (song.lyrics.contains(query)
      great, break loop to next song

    otherwise
      int queryCounter=0;
      find first index point in String array that matches query[queryCounter]
        using that as the start point, iterate through the String array for matches
```

When the iteration is complete, a Rank object is created to hold the Song, search phrase, start point and end points of the array section that matches.  In the Rank object is a method to count the number of characters and compensate for whitespace to calculate the rank.  This is then inserted into a PriorityQueue, where the top ten matches will be pulled from the original matchSet.

The problem is that this doesn't prevent false positives, and match ranks can get skewed.  For example, Aerosmith's Beyond Beautiful contains "... she loves me she loves you not ..."  With my process, I will match "... **she loves** me she loves **you** not...", so instead of a rank of 13, I will get a rank of 27.

What changes are necessary for me to weed out the false positives and incorrect rankings?

Comment: Basically, in the 'otherwise' block, after you find the first index that matches the start, you also have to look for possible other start points, and reset your start if you find another one.

Comment: I would recommend we have http://homework.stackoverflow.com/ where we just forward all homeworks there. :)

Comment: I wouldn't mind that, problem is every post for the past month I've tagged with -homework- has been edited to remove the tag.

Comment: @Neil: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Jason, please (as always) continue (as you have been) to follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.  You can mention in the text that it is homework, if you think that will give you better answers; but what's really important is the unique constraints that may apply to you depending on your school (the "special restrictions" in the list).

Comment: @The: Asking basic or homework questions on SO is acceptable, I don't think anyone is really arguing against that.

Comment: @Roger Pate Sorry, just wanted to help.

Comment: @Neil: I understand and appreciate that.  Community-run sites always have a few rough edges and miscommunications. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to add to what jjinguy said:

> Basically, in the 'otherwise' block, after you find the first index that matches the start, you also have to look for possible other start points, and reset your start if you find another one

I would keep a list of all possible matches in a song, and finally use the one that has the best rank. Simply resetting the start point might not catch the match with the best rank.

Maybe that isn't the best way, but the concern is still there.